# CLion CMakeLists.txt add argv arguments to configuration

Tags: c++, cmake, argv, clion

I have configuration in CMAkeLists.txt

```
set(SOURCE_FILES client/client.cpp)
add_executable(Client ${SOURCE_FILES} client/client.cpp)
```

So I can launch client.cpp in CLion (Shift + F10). But if I need to launch client.cpp with argv parameter (it has one integer as parameter) I must change configuration in CLion adding program arguments.

Maybe I can add some parameters using CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMakeList is only responsible for configuring your program, it does so by generating a Makefile, which then will build your program binary. 
Clion then launch the binary using the arguments you specified.